Iterate between different functions depending on the input value
I have data on the outside temperature
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   temp.out
'2023-01-18 00:00:00'   6.8
'2023-02-18 23:00:00'   1.5
'2023-03-04 00:00:00'   2.6
'2023-04-20 03:00:00'   -5.0
'2023-06-21 05:00:00'   11.9
'2023-08-10 19:00:00'   6.2
'2023-08-21 23:00:00'   -2.8
'2023-09-19 01:00:00'   5.7
'2023-11-3 07:00:00'    9.1
'2023-12-21 13:00:00'   -19.8", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(DT))

For each observation I determine the value of the COP indicator. It depends on the value of tzas. Since (currently) I have two functions describing the COP value depending on tzas (60 and 30), I calculate the value for intermediate values using a proportion (linear relationship).
COP.licz <- function(tout) {
  tzas = -0.78 * tout + 35.789
  COP.60 = 0.026 * tout + 2.937
  COP.30 = 0.0368 * tout + 3.46
  (COP.30 - COP.60) / (60 - 30) * (tzas - 30) + COP.30
}


df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate (
    tzas = -0.78 * temp.out + 35.789,
    COP.chw = COP.licz (temp.out)
  )

I get results left
> df1
                    DT temp.out  COP.chw
1  2023-01-18 00:00:00      6.8 3.719882
2  2023-02-18 23:00:00      1.5 3.598219
3  2023-03-04 00:00:00      2.6 3.624767
4  2023-04-20 03:00:00     -5.0 3.427471
5  2023-06-21 05:00:00     11.9 3.822061
6  2023-08-10 19:00:00      6.2 3.706901
7  2023-08-21 23:00:00     -2.8 3.487919
8  2023-09-19 01:00:00      5.7 3.695929
9  2023-11-03 07:00:00      9.1 3.767771
10 2023-12-21 13:00:00    -19.8 2.950173
> 

In the next version I have several (maybe more) COP functions (tzas): COP.60, COP.55, COP.50, COP.30.
I want to use these additional functions in COP.chw calculations
For example:
temp.out is -19.8, therefore tzas is 51.233
COP.chw will be calculated from the proportion between the values of COP.50 and COP.60
Using if or case_when seems to be a very forceful solution.
Example dependencies/functions
COP.60 = 0.026 * tout + 2.937
COP.55 = 0.029 * tout + 2.907
COP.50 = 0.0315 * tout + 3.001
COP.30 = 0.0368 * tout + 3.46


It seems you don't have a code problem/malfunction, just an optimization one. Maybe you'll find better help on codereview. Is this  the case?

You could use the following structure; Note that for tzas values less than 30 you would want to define another segment, as it currently returns null, as there is no matching blend.
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   temp.out
'2023-01-18 00:00:00'   6.8
'2023-02-18 23:00:00'   1.5
'2023-03-04 00:00:00'   2.6
'2023-04-20 03:00:00'   -5.0
'2023-06-21 05:00:00'   11.9
'2023-08-10 19:00:00'   6.2
'2023-08-21 23:00:00'   -2.8
'2023-09-19 01:00:00'   5.7
'2023-11-3 07:00:00'    9.1
'2023-12-21 13:00:00'   -19.8", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(DT))

blend <- function(tzas,low_cut,low_val,high_cut,high_val){
  (low_val - high_val) / (high_cut-low_cut) * (tzas - low_cut) + low_val
}

COP.licz_0 <- function(tout) {
  tzas = -0.78 * tout + 35.789
  
  COP.30 = 0.0368 * tout + 3.46
  COP.50 = 0.0315 * tout + 3.001
  COP.55 = 0.029 * tout + 2.907
  COP.60 = 0.026 * tout + 2.937

  which_cut <- as.integer(cut(tzas,breaks = c(30,50,55,60)))
  r <- switch(which_cut,
         blend(tzas,30,COP.30,50,COP.50),
         blend(tzas,50,COP.50,55,COP.55),
         blend(tzas,55,COP.55,60,COP.60)
          )
r
}
COP.licz <- Vectorize(COP.licz_0,vectorize.args = "tout")


df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate (
    tzas = -0.78 * temp.out + 35.789,
    COP.chw1 = COP.licz (temp.out)
  )


further comments :
the issue of a list result, is by tzas falling outside of defined breaks and returning NULL, so it has the solution I mentioned in my post, define proper bounds with proper behaviour.. and then it wont go back to you as a list .
yet,  if you dont want to and want to have NA values in those spaces though you can add .
if(is.null(r)){
    r <- NA_real_
  }
  r

to the end of COP.licz_0 function to turn nulls to numeric NA values

Can you explain what creating a vector is for? In the COP.chw1 column I get a list and I cannot perform further algebraic operations

Vectorize is necessary to turn a function that takes a single input at a time, and get it to perform over multiple one after another, like when you are mutating.

the issue of a list result, is by tzas falling outside of defined breaks and returning NULL, so it has the solution I mentioned in my post, define proper bounds with proper behaviour. if you dont want to and want to have NA values in those spaces though yo ucan add .  if(is.null(r)){     r <- NA_real_   }   r

My knowledge is limited, so I will ask further. My COP.count function did not require vectorization and worked inside mutate. COP.count_0 operate with a single value (COP.count_0 (-5.8) gives the result). So why is vectorization needed?
Your solution (with addition) works perfectly. Now I'm trying to understand.

It's because switch isn't vectorised   so perhaps one could try vectorising it instead. Or using dplyr::case_match()
